# The '' command was found in the module '', but the module could not be loaded

Tags: sql-server, powershell, module

No other questions seem to answer my question, so I am posting it here. I am exporting functions from .psm1 files. My structure is this

```
Modules (folder)
    CompanyName (folder)
        SQL (folder)
            SQL.psm1
```

My result of `Get-Module -Listavailable` returns the file containing my commands. (It is clear that my path is correct, otherwise this call would not return the functions I export in SQL.psm1)

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     0.0        SQL                                 {Import-BCPFile, Export-BCPFile}
```

However, I get an error trying to run the function,
**Import-BCPFile : The 'Import-BCPFile' command was found in the module 'SQL', but the module could not be loaded. For
more information, run 'Import-Module SQL'.**

I run `Import-Module SQL` and get another error,
**Import-Module : The specified module 'SQL' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
directory.**

Do you have any ideas why I can't call my function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were stuck like me, try importing the module like so,

`Import-Module "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Company\SQL"`

Importing the module will return any syntax errors in your module. I ended up missing a comma in my parameter list. Fixing this allowed me to run `Import-BCPFile` in my powershell window!!

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$BCPFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$Database,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$TableToImport,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$SQLServer = "." # <-- missing a comma!

    [switch]$Truncate = $False
)
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but my guess on the reason is that this question should be deleted (questions where the problem ends up being a typo generally are not very useful for others).

Comment: It's not fair to assume error messages were not clear in that I had a typo in my script - and finding the solution to this warrants a question?

Comment: Possibly, but to be honest relying on module auto-loading as a method of testing your module is unusual. Typically a module author would already be manually importing their module in the course of testing and so would find the syntax error immediately. Also, the error messages were very clear, but I think your folder structure is off and that's why importing by name didn't work and you had to do the extra step of importing by path (I think you should remove the `CompanyName` folder level completely. Consider naming your module `CompanySQL` or `Company.SQL`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me, I did not know importing the module was best-practice

Comment: @briantist the error message is pretty bad but easy to google. This question and answer helped me to find a problem in our toolchain. It is insane that powershell does not blow up when an import fail, and will only crash when calling a function.

Comment: @SimonBergot yeah it's a good point, and thank you for giving me a reason to look at the question again. I've upvoted the question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

When installing modules from a downloaded zip file (for example, when downloading AWS powershell tools as a zip file), this same error can also be caused if the Zip file was blocked as unsafe.

Unblocking the zip file before extracting modules seemed to fix this error for me.